# array of same id using getElementById error

Tags: php, arrays

i want to create array of same id or name using getElementById..

i have a "add button", when the user press this button, its generate a dropdown list(dynamic) which the value is get from mysql..

and its looks like this when the user press 3 times..

[image]
i want to create an array of this id, and store it to mysql..

**this is my JS code :**

```
  var menu_paket_array = document.getElementById('menu_paket').value;   

  alert(menu_paket_array);
```

the problem is, when i try to create this array(menu_paket_array), the value in this array is just the first id (Test 1) only..

how can i fix this?

thanks...

Comment: Don't use a single id for multiple elements, use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An ID must be unique on a page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). You can only use it on one element.

Instead, use a CSS class or element type to iterate ([here's a fiddle demonstrating this code](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/ZGLyn/)):

```
function alertValues() {
    var select, selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        select = selects[i];
        if (select.className && select.className.match(/CLASSNAME_TO_INCLUDE/)) {
            out += select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    alert(out);
}
```

A better solution, of course, would be to utilize a dom library like [jQuery](http://jquery.org) or [mootools](http://mootools.net), with which you could do something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    vals = [];
    $('select.CLASSNAME').each(function() { vals.push($(this).val()); });
    alert(vals.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the same id for more than one element is wrong. Id is to **uniquely** identify certain element. Using it for more elements defeats its -purpose. If you need that for i.e. CSS styling, then use `class` instead, which is designed just for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName(names);

Where names is the classname u generate for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning each element with `id='menu_paket'` (for the [reasons @WebnetMobile.com explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13557327/1755252)) assign `class='menu_paket'`.

Instead of `var menu_paket_array=document.getElementById('menu_paket').value;`, do

```
var temp_array = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_paket');
var menu_paket_array = [];
for(i in temp_array){
    menu_paket_array[] = temp_array[i].value;
}
```